# How to design a REST API for a webservice whose RPC method has overloaded meanings?

Tags: xml, rest

**Existing XML webservice**

- Processes XML-RPC style requests in which an *operation* element which identifies the method to dispatch to. For example:

  <protocol><operation>810</operation><user>...</user></protocol>
- The number of parameters vary.
- The XML-RPC handler interprets the 810 token to mean two things. If it receives an element **<user>** as a child element of **<protocol>**, it CREATEs an account. If it receives the element **<userExisting>** instead, it will attempt to log in the user.

**New JSON REST API design**

- I want to keep this to one REST endpoint e.g. */api/foobar*
- I can translate a user creation to a PUT */api/foobar/${user}*
- A user removal to a DELETE */api/foobar/${user}*
- My current design is to do a POST */api/foobar/${user}* with a body *{ "op":"login" }* for logging in and similarly for logout, the body *{ "op":"logout" }* will be sent.

What do you people think of this? Brickbats and bouquets are welcomed with constructive comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloaded POST for a RESTful API is a bit of a kludge, if you can avoid it. For the purposes of login, I would prefer to try to maintain statelessness - this would mean requiring the client to pass HTTP authorization on each request (this means passing the correct Authorization header each time). You use one of the usual authentication methods such as Basic on the first request.

Answer (score 1):

The end point should be at the URI `api/users` for all CRUD operations. DELETE and PUT are not supported in forms built with HTML 4 but if you are using Javascript to communicate then you'll be fine but you might want to expose create and delete operations via POST as well (possibly passing `_method=PUT|DELETE` in the POST payload).

For login the end point should be `api/login` but you would be better off using HTTP authentication here.

Asking for design reviews on stack overflow is good but you would be better off reading up on RESTful architectures to avoid wrong turns.

Comment: I would like to use HTTP auth and use all the arsenal that the HTTP protocol provides but I'm working with a bunch of people who would rather get things done quick (e.g. only use the minimum number of HTTP verbs). Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this for login and logout

```
POST /api/foobar/${user}/loginrequests

POST /api/foobar/${user}/logoutrequests
```

The server does not actually have to create a "request" resource if you don't want, but later you may change you mind and want to keep a record of logins and logouts.

Comment: From what I know, putting actions in the URIs is bad practice.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  However, I didn't put an action in the URI.  If I had put /RequestLogin then that would be an action.

Comment: /RequestLogin or /loginrequests doesn't have any impact. It could as well be /0f5cb891-6d64-49e7-9e5d-4b5f8b37f9a8 it wouldn't matter. It's the interaction model that matters, not the whole name/verb thing. It can be a smell but it certainly not a necessity.